# Will my Hidden Communities be indexed by Google?

Tags: support, profile-page

I have hidden one of communities which I don't want to expose anywhere, but my profile page for that community is indexed by Google. I'm not sure why that happens. Are there any settings I have to configure additionally?

**Information attached.**

[image]

Google Results

[image]

Please advise. I thought hiding the community would prevent indexing by a search engine as well. Is there something I missed?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

"Hidden Communities" are only hidden in the list of your network accounts in your profile. You can't hide your profile on a site entirely. So, if you hide your XYZ SE account, it won't be mentioned on your SO account profile. But your XYZ SE profile page is still public and can be retrieved by anyone or anything, including Google.

If you want to anonymize it, you can always change your display name and other information on only that site, or just create a new account (not associated with your other accounts).